# Dynamically Configure LDAP Server using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

The [Spring Security Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/) has an example of configuring an LDAP Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource().ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm looking for a way to initialize the the LDAP server dynamically, not in the configuration file. I can't seem to find any examples. The purpose of this is to implement SSO for a login form.

Comment: There is nothing here that configures an LDAP server. What is being configured is Spring, and it is being told how to use an existing and already configured LDAP server.

Comment: Sorry - what I meant was dynamically configure spring to connect to a pre-configured LDAP server

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to work with a lower-level directory, [ldaptive](http://www.ldaptive.org/docs/guide/authentication.html), to solve this problem.